# How to decode file names in $Recycle.Bin

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

When I list files in the `$Recycle.Bin` folder, the deleted files have file names that look like:

> `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3704213190-1981809790-211521205-1000\.���000200000008af358fa920f8faa779cf`

How does Windows map these to the names & paths of the original files?

I googled this but didn't manage to find the answer, not sure what to search for.

Comment: You could try searching for "*Recycle Bin Forensics*"  (see for example [here](https://dereknewton.com/2010/06/recycle-bin-forensics-in-windows-7-and-vista/))

Comment: Thanks. Hmm I think these files are just index files saying what the paths are, and I don't have the original files anymore in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files (`.���...` and `.����...`) are not actually put there by Windows during usual operation of the Recycle Bin (which produces the $I and $R files noted in HelpingHand's answer).

They are put there by Cygwin and MSYS2 respectively when a file cannot be deleted, e.g., because it is in-use, but would be able to be deleted under POSIX semantics.

The invalid characters are [`cyg`](https://github.com/cygwin/cygwin/blob/a97fbb58e209586f92381e90aaec8fb211287938/winsup/cygwin/syscalls.cc#L299-L322) and [`msys`](https://github.com/msys2/msys2-runtime/blob/9acb704afe9d9d8a090f2391e2bb88add63997c6/winsup/cygwin/syscalls.cc#L299-L322) transposed into the Unicode low surrogate area, to produce *invalid UTF-16 filenames*, for some reason.

Possibly the invalid UTF-16 to hide them from users, but mostly it just breaks tools, as many cross-platform tools and languages have issues interacting invalid UTF-16 filenames, because they expect to be able to use UTF-8 to manage filenames internally.

As of Cygwin 3 running on Windows 10 1809 or later, I understand that the only time you're going to see this behaviour is when a msys/cygwin executable tries to delete a running executable, such as itself; other than this case, Windows now implements sufficient POSIX semantics to delete, e.g., open documents, as Cygwin expects.

Presumably Cygwin/MSYS2 rely on Windows deleting all files from the recycle bin when it's emptied, as they don't appear to have anything to automatically clean up the files themselves, and the filenames do not match the filenames Windows uses when you delete things using Windows APIs.

So to answer your question, Windows cannot map them back to the original paths, as it did not put them there. The filename contains only an inode number and hash of the original path, so there's not enough information retained to do that mapping manually either.

Comment: Thanks for solving this mystery. I was running *Windows 7* when this happened.

Answer (score 1):

In the following working example, I have deleted the files:

- C:\zippy.zip
- C:\test.exe

Looking in the recycle bin directory for this user with `dir` reveals the following:

[image: dir and type commands]

So it appears for each deleted file, a file with a very similar name is created which references the original location of the deleted file which must be used during the restore operation.

In this case, zippy.zip is the $RDKXBG8.zip file and C:\test.exe is $RQLYPAP.exe.

Note: If you delete just the file of the pair which references the path, the file disappears from the Explorer view of the recycle bin and the 'actual' files remains.

Comment: Hmm thanks for looking into it. I tried this too and get a similar result. I'm not sure why I'm getting a file with the name `.���000200000008af358fa920f8faa779cf` though.